# Angular2 : Unable to Inject a service into another service

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, angular

I am build an Angular 2 app and I use quite a lot of services. I can inject those between them but I have one I can't inject.

> Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Language'(Settings, TranslateService, Config, undefined). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'Language' is decorated with Injectable.

It's the `AppStorage` service who doesn't want to be injected into the `Language` service (other services can be injected into the `Language` service fine). I did also try to inject `AppStorage` into other services (doesn't work).

The question is : What's wrong with `AppStorage` provider ?

[Direct link to AppStorage provider file](https://github.com/Bouzmine/metho/blob/2.0/app/providers/app-storage/app-storage.ts) (because it's kind of long)

Comment: The error seems to be about the Language service.  Do you have providers configured for all of the dependencies of Language?  It would be helpful if you showed your component tree (since that's where providers are configured) and the services that each component and each service tries to inject.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by having a provider configured for each service. Each of my providers are linked into the bootstrap. What I'm trying to do with the Language service is to inject into the App (root) component and then init it on deviceready event. The thing is I inject multiple other providers into Language and those all work. The only one not working is AppStorage and it won't inject in any other provider.

Comment: Your last commit was 8 hours ago, I built your project and did not receive the error, does it error out on device ready?

Comment: Sorry, now it's uploaded at its latest version with the error happening on deviceready

Comment: I suggest you try to create a minimal [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) that demonstrates the problem.   You'll receive more help that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here. Thanks for everyone's hint though. The problem was circular dependency injection. I tried to inject `AppStorage` into `Language` but `AppStorage` injected `Parse` which injected `Language`. I just removed `Language` injection from `Parse` everything started to work.

Comment: You can resolve circular dependency by injecting `injector:Injector` and then call for example `this.lang = injector.get(Language)` in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but in my case, I realized I didn't even need `Language` in `Parse`.

Answer (score 0):

This error **generally** occurs when you don't **decorate** a service or don't **provide** it.
Make sure you added a line in the top of your **hierarchical tree** structure providing the service:
`provide(AppStorage, {useClass : AppStorage})`.
This will generate an instance of AppStorage and provide to every component inside the **hierarchical tree** to all your components, directives and services.
For more info just take a look in this link: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html

Comment: I tried this (using provide in the bootstrap func), didn't work. Do you see a reason why it would inject into a component and not into another provider/service?

Comment: Because in angular2 the hierarquical tree is controlled in components. If you provide a service inside the main component it service will be available in all components. If you provide a service inside a inner component, it service will be available just in the hierarquical tree of this inner component.